# How to display a single plot in RShiny based on ifelse condition?

Tags: r, shiny

I have to display a single plot based on user selection. If the user selects two continuous variables, the output is a scatterplot. If the user selects one categorical and one continuous variable then the output is a boxplot.

For some reason, my boxplot is displaying but the scatterplot won't display. Rather, R Shiny tries to display both continuous variables using a boxplot and gives me this error:
**Warning: Continuous x aesthetic -- did you forget aes(group=...)?**

My code is below:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  #1. Select 1 of many continuous variables as y-variable 
  selectInput("y_varb", label="Y-axis variable",choices=names(data)[c(-1,-2,-14,-15,-16,-17)]),
  
  #2 Select any variable in dataset as x-variable
  selectInput("x_varb", label="X-axis variable", choices=names(data)),
  
  
  #3. Reset plot1 output after each selection
  plotOutput("plot", dblclick = "plot_reset")
  

)
server <- function(input, output) {
 
  remaining <- reactive({
    names(data)[-match(input$y_varb,names(data))]
  })
  
  observeEvent(remaining(),{
    choices <- remaining()
    updateSelectInput(session = getDefaultReactiveDomain(),inputId = "x_varb", choices = choices)
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggp1 <- ggplot(data, aes_string(input$x_varb, input$y_varb)) + geom_point()  
    ggp2 <- ggplot(data, aes_string(input$x_varb, input$y_varb)) + stat_boxplot()
    
    if(is.factor(input$x_varb)){ggp1} else {ggp2}

  })
     

}
```

Answer (score 1):

- `input$x_varb` is always going to be character. What you want to check is class of `data[[input$x_varb]]`.
- Don't create two plots for every selection, use `if`/`else` to create only plots which are necessary.
- `aes_string` is deprecated use `.data` in `aes` when passing column names as string.
- Finally, should the plots be opposite?  I mean when the `x_varb` is factor use `stat_boxplot` and when it is not use `geom_point` ?

You can try -

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
  if(is.factor(data[[input$x_varb]])) {
    plot <- ggplot(data, aes(.data[[input$x_varb]], .data[[input$y_varb]])) + stat_boxplot()
  } else {
    plot <- ggplot(data, aes(.data[[input$x_varb]], .data[[input$y_varb]])) + geom_point()  
  }
  plot
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I used the double square brackets and it worked. Legend!